# Files not accessible in Deployed Java class, but working locally in Web app developed on play 2.2 framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

I have a web application that I developed in Java over Play 2.2 framework.
When I am running the app locally one of my java class which is accessing some files in the project folders run fine.

After I create a jar file and run it, the java code is not able to read those files. The files are in the public folder and I have ensured packaged in the jar.

There are other files which I have referred from HTML and they are accessible but the java classes are not able to access the files.

Please help me solve this issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to access a file inside a jar. If I have understood your question. Please correct me if I am wrong

You could use something like this:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileFromJarFile);
```

If test.txt was in the root of your JAR file, you'd use:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.txt");
```

NOTE : The file and the java class needs to be in same jar file.

Comment: Initially the files are in the project folder and not in jar. Once I create a package of the project to run it on a different machine I create a jar using the [_play dist_] command. The issue is after packaging the application, the java classes can not access the files though the HTML can. Hope I am clear.

Comment: That is file. But you are creating a jar and then trying to access it so when doing it from project folder normal file read will work but if it is under the jar then you have to do it like above.

Answer (score 1):

The code was all fine in my case, the directory structure at the jar side was where I missed the part.

I had to keep the files/folders in the directory as same as that of the jar as @APaul said, I tried that but it did not work because I was using a batch to run the jar. My files should have been in the folder containing the batch file. My bad!

Anyways Thanks @APaul.